# When Instrumenting Zuul gateway with Jaeger, all routes marked GET

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, opentracing, jaeger

I am using [Zuul](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html#_router_and_filter_zuul) as an api-gateway in a spring-cloud micro-service app, so that every access  to *api-gateway/some-service/a_route* is redirected to */a_route* in a generic way (the discovery is backed by consul).

I am trying to use [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/) to instrument this system. And at this point I am using  [opentracing-spring-web-autoconfigure](https://dzone.com/articles/opentracing-spring-boot-instrumentation), because I cannot upgrade my spring boot/cloud version easily (I am using1.4.5.RELEASE Camden.SR7). So I just added the dependency, created the Jaeger tracer and redirect it to the docker all in one collector.

I have begin by instrumenting the gateway and It somewhat works => It generate span on the gateway, but all the route are marked :

*apigateway-service: GET*

and there is no information concerning the forwarded route at this level, the full route itself is store in a tag : http.url
"http://localhost:8080/collection-service/collections/projects/"

To be useful I would prefer to have span named :

*apigateway-service: GET collection-service/collections/projects/*

Can this be configured somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [it cannot](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-cloud/blob/2cc7d1d3666fb8b289f0f6223b662b5e72700895/instrument-starters/opentracing-spring-cloud-zuul-starter/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/cloud/zuul/TracePreZuulFilter.java#L56), but it wouldn't hurt to open an issue there with this suggestion.